# How to add custom row in Jaspersoft?

Tags: jasper-reports

I tried to create a report with Jaspersoft Studio following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qupDLprUoJE).
And I have created a table like that:

[image]

But I don't know how to add a custom row to below this table like that.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your report is made up of 3 areas.
1) Header Band(group header, page header, report header)
2) Detail Band
3) Footer Band(group footer, page footer, report footer)

[image]

If you want to add total area, you should add footer band and create variable for calculate total amount.

```
<variable name="TOTAL_AMOUNT" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Group" resetGroup="Your Group Name" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{AMOUNT}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

And put textField at footer band

```
<textFieldExpression class="java.math.BigDecimal"><![CDATA[$V{TOTAL_AMOUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
```

Comment: Ah... sorry, I'm not using Jaspersoft Studio, but using iReport.
But I think there is not much difference between Jaspersoft Studio and iReport.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the link and Video, you will get your solution

1) http://bekwam.blogspot.in/2011/06/expanding-crosstab-in-jaspersoft.html

2) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=unHbzWVvoRA